# How to sum rows in a data frame if the observations are NOT the NAs?

Tags: r

I've a data frame that contains 100 participants' data, and I want to calculate the Total scores of each participant. Some participants have data missing completely, however, I still want their Total score to be NA, Total = NA. 
Regarding the participants who have some/partial NAs, I want to sum all the scores that do NOT have NAs. In other words, I want to calculate the total of each row without calculating NAs. When I used `rowSums(df[2:10], rm.na = T)`, the function calculates the rows, but it gives 0s for those whom data are missing completely. 
Is there anyway to calculate each participants' total scores without deleting NAs and also assigns "NA" as a total score to the completely missing data? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use apply and specify a function that does exactly what you want- hope this helps:

```
apply(data,1,function(x){
    if(sum(is.na(x))==ncol(data)){
      return(NA)
    }else{
      return(sum(x,na.rm=T))
}})
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks, Chris.